# Login Signup PopUp

Tags: javascript

When I Open Login and signUp Portal it open with the both tab contents and then when I click on Login tab it open login tab content and on click register tab it open register tab page. But again after refresh the page popup showing both tabs content together![enter image description here][1]

I am unable to send you snapshot as I need 10 reputations to post image

This is the code of the popup:

```
<html>
<style>
.quick_signup{
    cursor:pointer;
}
body {font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.tab-box { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
.tab-box a {
  border:1px solid #DDD;
  color:#666666;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.tab-box a.activeLink { 
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 0; 
  padding: 6px 15px;
}
.tabcontent { border: 1px solid #ddd; border-top: 0; padding: 5px;}
.hide { display: none;}

.small { color: #999; margin-top: 100px; border: 1px solid #EEE; padding: 5px; font-size: 9px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inactive").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".inactive").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  
  });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/1.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="user">
<div id="modal-quicksignup" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="tab-box"> 
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="inactive" id="cont-1">Login</a> 
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="inactive " id="cont-2">SignUp</a> 

  </div>
         <a id="popup" onclick="div_show()"><?php echo $text_signin_register; ?></a>

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title main-heading"><?php echo $text_signin_register ?></h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="tabcontent" id="cont-1-1">
                <div class="col-sm-6 quick-login">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $text_returning ?></h4>
                    <span><?php echo $text_returning_customer ?></span>

                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value=""  id="input-email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-password"><?php echo $entry_password; ?></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary loginaccount"  data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>"><?php echo $button_login ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="<?php echo $forgotten; ?>"><?php echo $text_forgotten; ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="social_sign_in"> <b>Do you have your social account?</b>
                                     <div class="facebook_google_login_button">

                                       <div class="facebookButtonImageOverlay" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="return fblogin();">
                                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/login/"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="googleButtonImageOverlay" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="return fblogin();">
                                            <a href="https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=en"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/google.png" title="google" alt="google"></a>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabcontent" id="cont-2-1">

                <div class="col-sm-6 quick-register">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $text_new_customer ?></h4>
                    <span><?php echo $text_details; ?></span>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-telephone"><?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="telephone" value="" id="input-telephone" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-password"><?php echo $entry_password; ?></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="input-password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
                    <div class="buttons">
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />&nbsp;<?php echo $text_agree; ?>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary createaccount"  data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" ><?php echo $button_continue; ?></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary createaccount" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" ><?php echo $button_continue; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).delegate('.quick_signup', 'click', function(e) {
    $('#modal-quicksignup').modal('show');
});
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.quick-register input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.quick-register .createaccount').trigger('click');
    }
});
$('.quick-register .createaccount').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=common/quicksignup/register',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.quick-register input[type=\'text\'], .quick-register input[type=\'password\'], .quick-register input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.quick-register .createaccount').button('loading');
            $('#modal-quicksignup .alert-danger').remove();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.quick-register .createaccount').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.modal-quicksignup .form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if(json['islogged']){
                 window.location.href="index.php?route=account/account";
            }
            if (json['error_name']) {
                $('.quick-register #input-name').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-register #input-name').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_email']) {
                $('.quick-register #input-email').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-register #input-email').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_telephone']) {
                $('.quick-register #input-telephone').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-register #input-telephone').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_password']) {
                $('.quick-register #input-password').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-register #input-password').focus();
            }
            if (json['error']) {
                $('#modal-quicksignup .modal-header').after('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin:5px;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + '</div>');
            }

            if (json['now_login']) {
                $('.quick-login').before('<li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_account; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_account; ?></span> <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"><li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li><li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li><li><a href="<?php echo $transaction; ?>"><?php echo $text_transaction; ?></a></li><li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li><li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>"><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li></ul></li>');

                $('.quick-login').remove();
            }
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#modal-quicksignup .main-heading').html(json['heading_title']);
                success = json['text_message'];
                success += '<div class="buttons"><div class="text-right"><a onclick="loacation();" class="btn btn-primary">'+ json['button_continue'] +'</a></div></div>';
                $('#modal-quicksignup .modal-body').html(success);
            }
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.quick-login input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.quick-login .loginaccount').trigger('click');
    }
});
$('.quick-login .loginaccount').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=common/quicksignup/login',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.quick-login input[type=\'text\'], .quick-login input[type=\'password\']'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.quick-login .loginaccount').button('loading');
            $('#modal-quicksignup .alert-danger').remove();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.quick-login .loginaccount').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('#modal-quicksignup .form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            if(json['islogged']){
                 window.location.href="index.php?route=account/account";
            }

            if (json['error']) {
                $('#modal-quicksignup .modal-header').after('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin:5px;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + '</div>');
                $('.quick-login #input-email').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-login #input-password').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('.quick-login #input-email').focus();
            }
            if(json['success']){
                loacation();
                $('#modal-quicksignup').modal('hide');
            }

        }
    });
});
//--></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function loacation() {
    location.reload();
}
//--></script>
```

Comment: you can show your example in jsfiddle also. not always images help.

Comment: You could upload your image [here](http://imgur.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have 2 options to solve it first is jquery and second one is css.

1) Jquery

On load trigger click event.

```
$('#cont-1').click();
```

**OR**

---

2) CSS

Add **hide** class in second tab

```
<div class="tabcontent hide" id="cont-2-1">
```

and add **activeLink** class for login

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="inactive activeLink" id="cont-1">Login</a>
```

Example of css solution : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/2qw9877d/

Example of Jquery solution : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7zc2r9Lm/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52m0g7up/1/)

REPLACE below code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inactive").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".inactive").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  
  });
```

with THIS CODE: **UPDATED**

```
 $("#cont-2-1").hide();
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".inactive").click(function () {
         var curClick = this.id;
         $(".inactive").removeClass("tab-box-active");
         $("#" + curClick).addClass("tab-box-active");
         $(".tabcontent").hide();
         $("#" + curClick + "-1").fadeIn();
     });
 });
```

**CSS:UPDATED**

```
.quick_signup {
    cursor:pointer;
}
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.tab-box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.tab-box a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tab-box .inactive {
    background-color: #eee;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
    color:#666666;
}
.tab-box-active {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding: 6px 15px !important;
}
.tabcontent {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.small {
    color: #999;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: @Sandy Check if this help you.

Comment: Example of css solution : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/2qw9877d/ helps for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is done but I need to define an  extra class to make one of the tab default active